# How to set a column default value to Null? (in slick)

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

```
case class Account(var email:String, var pass:String, var familyId: Int, var accessId: Int, id: Option[Int] = None)

// A Accounts table with 5 columns: id, email, pass, familyId, accessId
class Accounts(tag: Tag) extends Table[Account](tag, "ACCOUNTS") {

  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  def email = column[String]("EMAIL")
  def pass = column[String]("PASS")
  def familyId = column[Int]("FAMILY_ID")                            // TODO: add fk family_id
  def accessId = column[Int]("ACCESS_ID")                            // TODO: add fk access_id

  def * = (email, pass, familyId, accessId, id.?) <> (Account.tupled, Account.unapply)

}
```

After creating table with such structure all columns in table are `Not Null`.

So how to set them to `Nullable` and set their value to `Null`?

Comment: I think you probably want to just [use the slick code generator](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/code-generation.html) to generate this stuff...  (this doesn't answer the question, I know ... it hopefully makes the question moot!).   The actual answer to the question involves declaring the columns as an Option for the the value, but since we generate this stuff, I haven't needed to understand the details :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can do this by declaring field that is `nullable` as `Option[T]` in the `case class`

Lets say we have `User` class and we want `age` value to be `nullable` and the default value of age is `null`. So we declare our class like below. notice age is `Option[Int]`.

```
case class User(name: String, age: Option[Int])

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def age = column[Option[Int]]("age", O.Default(None)) //notice default value is None which translates to Null in database
  def * = (name, age) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

*age field is nullable and its default value is null*